# JS - Замена символов в файле

Tags: javascript

Есть файл, который содержит:

```
0: {x: "44.6438331", y: "33.7276571"}
1: {x: "44.6582512", y: "33.7125156"}
2: {x: "44.6706244", y: "33.6888559"}
3: {x: "44.6787069", y: "33.6812012"}
4: {x: "44.6665003", y: "33.6640363"}
5: {x: "44.6556112", y: "33.6593971"}
6: {x: "44.6795279", y: "33.7620340"}
7: {x: "44.6782635", y: "33.7598484"}
```

Необходимо убрать "0..7:", оставив только значение в скобках.
Буду рад подсказке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос и вам нужен скрипт для Node.js, то можно так:

```js
'use strict';

const fs  = require('fs');

fs.writeFileSync(
  'test.txt',
  fs.readFileSync('test.txt', 'utf8').replace(/^\d+: /gm, '')
);
```